# Произвольные поля в рубрики WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо, чтобы в меню "Записи" - "Рубрики" были свои поля (текст, изображение), которые можно добавлять для каждой новой рубрики и выводить их в общем списке с рубриками.
Весь день просидел в поиске, рабочий вариант так и не нашел.

Comment: как вариант : http://dmitriydenisov.com/wordpress/wp-theme/wordpress-custom-fields.html

Comment: второй вариант : http://wp-kama.ru/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, Вам поможет плагин "Advanced Custom Fields". Есть много информации в интернете на русском языке по поводу его настройки.